# Customizing Django-PayPal View

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

I am using django paypal to allow users to make a payment on my site however i have a few queries.

The way how it is currently working for me is that i have a template called profile.html. When a user clicks the button "Click for more subscription options" he will be redirected to the subscriptions.html template showing a table of the subscriptions and a paypal button. When the button is clicked, the user gets redirected to another template called paypal.html which shows another paypal button derived from django-paypal's forms.py

My question here would be how i can modify the paypal view such that i can do away with the paypal.html and direct the user directly to the actual paypal website when he clicks the paypal button in subscription.html?

I hope my description of the question is clear enough.

in my views.py:

```
def paypal(request):
    paypal_dict = {"business":settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,"amount": "1.00","item_name": "Milk" ,"invoice": "12345678", "notify_url": "%s%s" % (settings.SITE_NAME, reverse('paypal-ipn')),"return_url": "http://rosebud.mosuma.net",}
    # Create the instance.
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    context = {"form": form.sandbox()}
    return render_to_response("paypal.html", context)
```

in my profile.html:

```
....
<INPUT TYPE="submit" Value="Click to find out subscription plans" name="subscription" onClick="/subscribe/>
```

in my subscription.html:

```
<form method="post" action="paypal/">
<select name="subscription_input" id="id_subscription" style = "float: center">
<option>Monthly</option>
<option>Yearly</option>
</select></br></br>

{{ form }}
</form>
```

in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^paypal/$', 'r2.views.paypal', name='paypal'),
url(r'^profile/paypal/$', 'r2.views.paypal', name='paypal'),
```

Comment: Why not put the paypal forms on the subscriptions.html template?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to go directly to the PayPal website the moment he clicks the PayPal button in subscription.html, you will have to render the PayPal form in subscription.html instead of paypal.html. Moreover you need to subclass the PayPalPaymentsForm in forms.py to override the default PayPal image of "Buy Now" because you want your own button to work in the first place.

---

**forms.py**

```
from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm
from django.utils.html import format_html

class ExtPayPalPaymentsForm(PayPalPaymentsForm):
    def render(self):
        form_open  = u'''<form action="%s" id="PayPalForm" method="post">''' % (self.get_endpoint())
        form_close = u'</form>'
        # format html as you need
        submit_elm = u'''<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success my-custom-class">'''
        return format_html(form_open+self.as_p()+submit_elm+form_close)
```

---

**views.py**

```
from .forms import ExtPayPalPaymentsForm
def paypal(request):
    paypal_dict = {"business":settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,"amount": "1.00","item_name": "Milk" ,"invoice": "12345678", "notify_url": "%s%s" % (settings.SITE_NAME, reverse('paypal-ipn')),"return_url": "http://rosebud.mosuma.net",}
    # Create the instance.
    form = ExtPayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    context = {"form": form.sandbox()}
    return render_to_response("subscription.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021-04-08 in Version 1.1.1 of `django-paypal` the `self.get_endpoint()` has been changed to be `self.get_login_url()`.

https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release_notes.html#version-1-1-1-2021-04-08